# can I get my screen working properly again?

Tags: windows-10, display, asus-laptop

I bought an AsusPro PC, But unfortunately, It had fallen on the ground. now I can see on the screen that some places are dimmer than others. I'm literally seeing a continuous gradient of brightness from the bottom right corner to the up left. is there some piece of software that is able to balance the brightness again?

Comment: No. The screen needs to be replaced.